# Why program exits before async finishes its task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

I see it as a very redundant question but i did really dig deep and didn't find answer.. I am using a very dummy example mentioned [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async), the first one.

I have created a windows form application where i removed the auto generated code in the main and i copied and past the code in the example site.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    //[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create task and start it.
        // ... Wait for it to complete.
        Task task = new Task(ProcessDataAsync);
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
    }

    static async void ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        // Start the HandleFile method.
        Task<int> task = HandleFileAsync("D:\\test.txt");

        // Control returns here before HandleFileAsync returns.
        // ... Prompt the user.
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait patiently " +
            "while I do something important.");

        // Wait for the HandleFile task to complete.
        // ... Display its results.
        int x = await task;
        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + x);
    }

    static async Task<int> HandleFileAsync(string file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HandleFile enter");
        int count = 0;

        // Read in the specified file.
        // ... Use async StreamReader method.
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string v = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            // ... Process the file data somehow.
            count += v.Length;

            // ... A slow-running computation.
            //     Dummy code.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                int x = v.GetHashCode();
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    count--;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("HandleFile exit");
        return count;
    }
}
```

The output is:

> HandleFile enter
>   The thread 0x8184 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   The thread 0x6764 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   The program '[42112] testasyncforms.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Please wait patiently while I do something important.

So, why program exits without printing "HandleFile exit"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this `new Task(ProcessDataAsync);` does not do what you want.

Since the `async void` pattern is used only for async event handling, in your case I would recomment you to return a `Task` by the `ProcessDataAsync` method and then simply `.Wait()` on that task.

Comment: i changed it to be like this "Task task = ProcessDataAsync();" and i have got an exception :(

Comment: also changing void to Task..but still the same issue giving me "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"

Comment: `Task task = ProcessDataAsync();` while `static async Task ProcessDataAsync()` however, you'd better read some articles before doing this.

Comment: i have did the same and still generates exception of invalid operation..i have already read some articles about it and i know how thw workflow goes but this dummy piece is making me crazy

Comment: @MohamedSalem u dont need to .start after that.

Comment: okay..just removed task.start() and it worked ..sorry for inconvenience :)